# UITableView inside UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

I'm implementing a custom cell. There is a button inside the cell. When user click the button, it will pop up a dropdown menu which is a tableview.

But when I click inside the dropdown menu, it is not responding, and the outside tableviewcontroller is responding.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you can do like this `UIViewController` -> `UITableView` -> `UITableViewCell` -> `UIButton` (On Tap) -> Pop up DropDown ....

Comment: @Mahesh I mean the dropdown menu is not respoding

Comment: i said use UIViewController instead of UITableViewController.

Comment: Will you publish your code here?

Comment: we cant see any button here, show your code how you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown is larger than its containing cell. Thus, all touches outside of the cell are not sended to the dropdown. To solve this problem, you should insert your dropdown into a view which covers the complete area of the dropdown. This is usually the outer table view.

Answer (score 0):

In funcition of click button u add tableView and  get CGRect of this button, and create new table and add to view.

```
TableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
            [TableView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
            TableView.delegate = self;
            TableView.dataSource = self;
            [TableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
            [self.view addsubView:TableView];
```